# Using dictionary keys in pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote the following code in which I create a dictionary of `pandas` dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

classification = pd.read_csv('classification.csv')

thresholdRange = np.arange(0, 70, 0.5).tolist()

classificationDict = {}

for t in thresholdRange:
    classificationDict[t] = classification

for k, v in classificationDict.iteritems():
    v ['Threshold'] = k
```

In this case, I want to create a column called 'Threshold' in all the pandas dataframes in which the keys of the dictionary are the values. However, what I get with the code above is the same value in all dataframes. What am I missing here? Perhaps I am complicating things for myself with this approach, but I'd greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: are you sure this code runs? You import `numpy` and then use arange without `np.`? And `tolist()` probably needs the parentheses?

Comment: Thanks @Ilja. I just edited the question. I typed this on my smartphone and I missed those important details.

Comment: Well, you should have waited until you are in front of your computer - or is it _so_ urgent ;)  The code example should be a minimal working example. When you try to create one, you'll often find the issue yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I got your question wrong. Now this is the issue:

Obviously, classification (a pandas dataframe, I suppose) is a mutable object, and adding a mutable object to a list or a dict makes strange (for python-beginners) behaviour. The *same* object is added. If you change one of the list entries, all get changed. Try this:

```
a = [1]
b = [a, a]
b[0] = 2
print(b[1])
```

This is what happens to your dict.
You have to add different objects to the dict. Probably the dataframe has a `.copy()`-method to do this. Alternatively, I found this post for you, with (in essence) the same problem, there are further solutions there:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/6053327

Comment: I confirm, if you add .copy() at the end of classificationDict[t] = classification the code works.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you get the same value. You are doing the same assignment over and over again in

```
for k, v in classificationDict.iteritems():
```

because your `v`s are all identical, you assigned them in the first `for`
Did you try debugging yourself, and print `classification`? I assume that it is only the first line?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Ilja. I did find an answer on how to achieve a similar result with `awk`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42891531/adding-column-to-csv-file-with-awk-using-number-sequence. Do you have any advice on how to approach this in Python?

Comment: wait, you want to have 140 files? each with a column with identical entries? Then I misunderstood your question, i thought you want to have the sequence inside a column... sorry :( I will adjust a little

Comment: I added a new answer, I think, I will delete this, since it does not address your question...