# Adding column to CSV file with awk using number sequence

Tags: awk

I am trying to use the following `awk` command. My goal is to use the number sequence to create a new column in my files using the values of the sequence. In the end, I want to generate CSV files with each of the new columns:

```
for i in $(seq 0 0.5 70); do 
awk -F"," 'BEGIN {OFS = ","} {$7=$(echo $i); print}' ClassificationTest.csv > new_columns_$i.csv;
done
```

The input CSV file looks like this:

```
Sample1,Probe1,Temp1,ProbeType1,SampleType1,Ratio1
Sample2,Probe2,Temp2,ProbeType2,SampleType2,Ratio2
```

The expected results should look like this:

A file named new_columns_20.0.csv

```
Sample1,Probe1,Temp1,ProbeType1,SampleType1,Ratio1,20.0
Sample2,Probe2,Temp2,ProbeType2,SampleType2,Ratio2,20.0
```

My goal is to have a file for each value of the number sequence. I am having a hard time passing the values of the sequence as arguments. Can someone please provide help on how to perform this? Thank you.

Comment: Please, some sample data and expected results.

Comment: Hello @James Brown. Please see the edits. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is one way of doing it

```
for i in {0..140}; 
do awk -F, -v OFS=, -v i=$i '{$7=i/2}1' input > output_$i; 
done
```

or completely within `awk`

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{for(i=0;i<=70;i+=0.5) 
                      {$7=i; print > "output_"i}}' input
```

Comment: the second one looks neater, +1

Comment: I agree. Both options worked, but I prefer the second option because the file names reflect the value being added into the new column. Thank you very much for your help @karafka.